# Google Spreadsheet function for email tracking

Tags: email, templates, spreadsheet, tracking

I am trying to learn how to create functions in a Google Spreadsheet that I will be using to track success rate of template emails. Here is the [example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AppkK6kryA8qdGNuTmtjdXZiUklBZEg1N3JWMWpmcmc&usp=sharing).

What would the functions be for 'Template Tracking' sheet in C2, D2 and E2?

Essentially if a value exists in 'Email Tracking' column D then count it (if nothing there, then don't) and the create sum in appropriate place on 'Template Tracking' sheet based on 'Template #' in 'Email Tracking' column C.

Answer (score 0):

While still no conclusion about a function, I did find that using pivot tables was a very easy workaround.

Can see how that looks [here.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AppkK6kryA8qdEpUSXdDbGpRNDRDVTd0ak1wRWo5MVE&usp=sharing)

Welcome any further ideas about a function but hope this is helpful to others who might want to use it.